# Can I make a single computer out of 3 with lxd cluster?

Tags: virtualization, lxc

I'm setting up a [LXD cluster](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clustering/) on 3 machines.

Though I'm concerned if a single container (a virtual machine) use all the resources of 3 machine.

I mean

1. Does a single container use all 3 machine's CPU?
2. Does it fully use 3 machine's RAM?

As for storage I'm not sure how container's data is stored.

3. Is data stored in redundancy in RAID or something? Haven't found a page about it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, LXD cluster allow you to use 3 machine  only to manage backup, if one node goes down. You can span single container that can use all 3 machines.